# For $k$ a positive integer, and $\delta \in (0,1)$, find the upper bound for: $\frac{\sqrt{(1- \delta)^{2k} + 4\delta} \ - (1-\delta)^k}{2\delta}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've just got back to study some subjects that require maths, and my skill is pretty rusty. After some algebraic manipulation I arrive at the expression in the title. What should I do next?

Comment: Multiply the numerator and denominator by a conjugate.

Answer (score 1):

Using @Display name's hint
$$A=\frac{\sqrt{(1- \delta)^{2k} + 4\delta} \ - (1-\delta)^k}{2\delta}=\frac{\sqrt{(1- \delta)^{2k} + 4\delta} \ - (1-\delta)^k}{2\delta}\frac{\sqrt{(1- \delta)^{2k} + 4\delta} \ + (1-\delta)^k}{ \sqrt{(1- \delta)^{2k} + 4\delta} \ + (1-\delta)^k}$$
$$A=\frac {4\delta}{2\delta}\frac 1{ \sqrt{(1- \delta)^{2k} + 4\delta} \ + (1-\delta)^k}=\frac 2{ \sqrt{(1- \delta)^{2k} + 4\delta} \ + (1-\delta)^k}< \frac 2{2 (1- \delta)^{k}}$$